# How to Calculate speed of body required for collision to have specific output

Tags: momentum, velocity, collision

I'm trying to calculate the speed the bolt of an airsoft rifle has to go in order for a bb to have a specific speed.

for example:

the bb weighs 0.2g and the bolt I have weights 100g, I would like the bb to fly at as close to the limit as possible which is just over $150ms^{-1}$.

I tried using the momentum equation but don't know the final velocity of the bolt so I cant calculate the starting velocity

Is there any way to calculate what speed the bolt must be going for the bb to be moving at $150ms^{-1}$

Comment: Not every physicist know how a   airsoft rifle function, what the bolt and the bb is. can you give a  explanation?

Comment: just think of it as a long rod of mass 100g, hitting a small sphere of mass 0.2g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the equations for elastic collision, which you find in wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision and you find the exct numbers

Answer (score 1):

In my air rifle, the bb's are propelled by compressed air.  It does not have a bolt. However, If you have a spring driven bolt, and assume that the mass of the bolt is large compared to that of the bb, and that the collision conserves energy, then the speed of the bb relative to the bolt will be reversed in the collision.  This means that the speed of the bb just after the collision will be almost twice the speed of the bolt just  before the collision. If the mass difference is not large, and you assume that energy is conserved, then both speeds are reversed relative to the center of mass.

Comment: I understand this far, but I'm more concerned about precise numbers. This is because if I go too powerful, the rifle will be illegal, and I don't want that

Comment: If you have a spring powered bolt, weigh the bolt to get its mass. Determine its  motion while in contact with the spring, and hang  weight on the spring to determine its constant. With this information you can calculate the speed of the bolt when it hits the bb.  The speed of the bb will be less than twice this speed.